# Fetch updated argument for a method using AspectJ

Tags: aop, aspectj

A class where aspect join point happens

```
class A {
 ...
 @PointCutHere
 public void method(List<String> arg1) {
    arg1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
    ...
 }
}
```

CustomAspect.java

```
@Aspect
class CustomAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(PointCutHere)")
    public void pointCut(){
    }

    @Around("pointCut()")
    public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        joinPoint.proceed();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        System.out.println(((List<String>)args[0]).toString());
    }
}
```

Say, another class calls A.method(new LinkedList());

Here, I am trying to print inside @Around the latest updated value of an argument passed into the method.

In this example,

the actual output I am getting is: []

expected output I want: ["A", "B"]

In my understanding, since it's Java, the arguments are pass by reference. Why isn't AspectJ not showing the expected updated value?

Comment: Please read through : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/286014

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question. It explains call by reference for normal objects which are **not** `String` instances.

Comment: The link was to provide clarity on OPs understanding on “pass by reference” , rest I thought was obvious to find out . My bad if it was not clear enough

Answer (score 1):

A `String` is not a normal object. Quote from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> **Strings are constant;** their values cannot be changed after they are created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because **String objects are immutable** they can be shared.

I.e. that `String` instances, while behaving like objects otherwise, behave more like primitives when it comes to assigning new values to them.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. My bad. I simplified the problem statement and incorrectly, gave example with string. Updated the problem.

Comment: Why did you "simplify" code which was super simple already, thus falsifying it? Now you completely changed the question after the fact, rendering my formerly correct answer useless. I.e. that both R.G's comment and my answer were a waste of time. What is worse, answer looks false now. What you should have done instead as a courtesy to the volunteers trying to help you is to accept the correct answer, write a new question and answer that one instead by yourself or wait for an answer, whatever.

Comment: My bad again on this. Really appreciate your time and effort in helping out with this. I have upvoted the comments and your solution, because it helped in shaping up the question. In lieu of time, I have updated the question and posted what worked out for me. If you disagree, please feel free to downvote. You have the right for helping me with this. @kriegaex

Comment: No, I don't downvote, especially not revenge downvotes. That is beneath me. Don't worry, I was just disappointed and a bit angry for a moment, life goes on.

Answer (score 0):

The miss was re-assigning the entire variable instead of using setters. When I replaced `arg1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B");` to `arg1.addAll(["A", "B"]);`, it worked.

So, never re-assign the variable. Use the objects method (setter or any other method()) for this purpose.